# Consulta a mysql con Google Chart no trae datos

Tags: php, mysql, google-api

Perdon soy nuevo en PHP y estoy haciendo graficos con Google chart y no me trae los datos que consulto a mysql...les adjunto datos de la consulta  y luego de la configuracion del script ..La consulta es a una tabla que contiene consumos de combustible por patente ...tengo 2 input y cuando consulto no trae nada

```
  <?php
#error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
if(isset($_POST['btConsulta']))
{
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "movedb");
 $patente= $_POST['patente'];
 $anno= $_POST['año'];
 $fech = array();
 $cant = array();
 $i= 0;
 $meses = array('','Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo','Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre');
 for ($x=1;$x<=12;$x=$x+1){
    $cantidad[$x]=0;
 }



 $sql= "SELECT Fecha_Carga as Fechas, ROUND(SUM(Cantidad_Litros),2) as Litros  from tablaunion1 where YEAR(Fecha_Carga) = '$anno' and Patente = '$patente' group by MONTH(Fecha_Carga)";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

    $y = date("Y", strtotime($row['Fechas']));
    $mes =(int)date("m", strtotime($row['Fechas']));


    if ($y==$anno){
        $cantidad[$mes] = $cantidad[$mes]+$row['Litros'];

    }






 }


}

?>
```

> El script del grafico es

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() 
{
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
               ['Mes','Cantidades'],
               <?php

               for ($x=1;$x<=12;$x=$x+1){
               ?>
                ['<?php echo $meses[$x]; ?>', <?php echo $cantidad[$x] ?>],
                <?php } ?>

              ]);

            var options = {title: 'Consumo mensual'
            };  

            // Instantiate and draw the chart.
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('barChart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
         }



</script>
```

Agrego imagen de pantalla

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG3KX.jpg]

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos el HTML generado en la zona de `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()`? Pulsa "Ver código fuente" en la página para ver lo que PHP ha generado y así poder reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Parece que no puede ser un problema de la consulta, puedes hacer un var_dump($result) antes del while y decirnos qué sale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la consulta a la base de datos debes recorrer el array del resultado de la query.

```
$sql= "SELECT Fecha_Carga as Fechas, ROUND(SUM(Cantidad_Litros),2) as Litros  from tablaunion1 where YEAR(Fecha_Carga) = '$anno' and Patente = '$patente' group by MONTH(Fecha_Carga)";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $y = date("Y", strtotime($row['Fechas']));
        $mes =(int)date("m", strtotime($row['Fechas']));

        if ($y==$anno){
            $cantidad[$mes] = $cantidad[$mes]+$row['Litros'];
        }
     }
```

Por otro lado, la condición del año ya la has incluido en la query, así que el `if ($y==$anno)` puedes eliminarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Carmen...!

Comment: Un placer, para eso estamos :)